# Enable / disable captions using React-Player

Tags: reactjs, video, react-player, cue-points

I'm using React-Player, and pretty new to this library.
Here is my code where I'm using React-Player:

```
 <ReactPlayer
            ref={video}            
            url={[{ src: urlSrc, type: 'video/mp4' }]}                
            config={{
              file: {
                tracks: [
                  { kind: 'subtitles', src: urlSub, srcLang: 'en', 
                    default: true, label: "English" }               
                ]
            }}
          />
```

**So my question is:**
How can I know if captions are playing?
I'm looking for something like in HTML-

```
 if(video.textTracks[0].mode !== "showing")
     video.textTracks[0].mode = "showing";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your urlSub should be. vtt file,  for me is working file

<ReactPlayer
playing
controls
url={RazorVideo}
config={{ file: {

```
                        tracks: [
                            {kind: 'subtitles', src: vtt, srcLang: 'English', default: true,color:'orange'},
                        ]
                    }}}
                    onReady={() => console.log('ready')}
                    onStart={() => console.log('onStart')}
                    onPause={() => console.log('onPause')}
                    onEnded={() => console.log('onEnded')}
                    onError={() => console.log('onError')}
                    onPlay={() => {console.log('onPlay')}}

            />
```

vtt file is

WEBVTT

00:00:03.300 --> 00:00:05.400
Forecasting and planning has entered a new

00:00:05.500 --> 00:00:09.600
era which requires radically different challenge approaches.

00:00:10.100 --> 00:00:12.100
I'll use using challenges faced by

00:00:12.100 --> 00:00:13.400
some of our early customers.

00:00:14.500 --> 00:00:16.700
One of our special where customers replace

00:00:17.700 --> 00:00:20.000
80% of their product portfolio every year.

00:00:20.200 --> 00:00:23.100
Historical data for each new product is fast.

00:00:23.900 --> 00:00:25.700
Another is a disputer who has

00:00:25.700 --> 00:00:28.100
grown 1900% in three years.

00:00:28.200 --> 00:00:30.600
It is critically important to capture many

00:00:30.700 --> 00:00:33.300
different market dynamics to forecast their sales.

00:00:33.700 --> 00:00:36.400
Yet another has seen over 70% of their

00:00:36.400 --> 00:00:39.100
business transition to Amazon and need to be

00:00:39.100 --> 00:00:42.000
Proactive system that would provide daily actionables.

00:00:43.600 --> 00:00:45.400
To solve this, we built an

00:00:45.400 --> 00:00:47.800
intelligent forecasting and planning engine.

00:00:48.000 --> 00:00:50.500
Critical to our effort were multiple features.

00:00:50.700 --> 00:00:53.400
Incorporate multiple data sources seamlessly.

00:00:53.500 --> 00:00:57.300
However disparate their structure was build support

00:00:57.400 --> 00:01:00.300
for behavioral AI which models a channel's

00:01:00.300 --> 00:01:03.400
behavior carefully rather than blindly slap an

00:01:03.400 --> 00:01:08.400
AutoML model on incorporate human feedback allowing

00:01:08.400 --> 00:01:11.000
persistent adjustments and learning from them.

00:01:11.600 --> 00:01:15.000
Build a rapid feedback mechanism that enables

00:01:15.000 --> 00:01:17.200
pro response to challenges and opportunities.

Comment: Please format your answer correctly.